# TableSorter - Apply Icon to unsorted Columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table, And I have sort up and sort down icon's applied in the following CSS

```
.tablesorter-headerSortDown {
    background-image: url("../images/sort_down.png");
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}
.tablesorter-headerSortUp   {
    background-image: url("../images/sort_up.png");
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}
```

I have tried similar CSS for `.tablesorter-icon` to apply an **unsorted image** (a left arrow instead of up and down)

I have also tried css for `.tablesorter-header`, which overwrites the up and down arrows, and is always present at all times.

Is there a CSS class for this? Am I supposed to be handling this initialization?

Thanks for reading,

**Tablesorter init**

```
$(function() {
  $(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
      widthFixed: false,
      sortList: [
            [0,0],
            [1,0]
        ],
        showProcessing: true,


      // this is the default setting
      cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",

      // initialize zebra and filter widgets
      widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "stickyHeaders"],

      headers: { 0: { filter: true, sorter: true },
                 1: { filter: true, sorter: true },
                 2: { filter: false, sorter: true },
                 3: { filter: false, sorter: true },
                 4: { filter: false, sorter: false },
                 5: { filter: false, sorter: false },
                 6: { filter: false, sorter: false },
                 7: { filter: false, sorter: false },
                 8: { filter: false, sorter: false }},

      widgetOptions: {
        stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#connectionGrid',
        stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
        stickyHeaders_yScroll : '#tablesorter',
        stickyHeaders_addCaption: true,
        // include child row content while filtering, if true
        filter_childRows  : true,
        // class name applied to filter row and each input
        filter_cssFilter  : 'tablesorter-filter',
        filter_reset : '.clearall',
        // search from beginning
        filter_startsWith : false,
        // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
        filter_ignoreCase : true,
        filter_functions : { 0 : true, 2 : true },
        sortInitialOrder: "desc",
        zebra : ["odd-row", "even-row" ]
      }

    });
```

edit: this is what it looks like now, I would like to add an arrow for all unsorted columns. 
[image]

Comment: So did you apply it yo `tablesorter-headerUnSorted` and make the rule more specific?

Comment: Applying css to that class also results in no change. I had also tried `tablesorter-headerSortNone`

Comment: I notice as well that unsorted columns do not have that class on my table

Comment: What is the exact plugin you are using?

Comment: I am using tablesorter filter widget from the tablesorter.widgest.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using css for the original [tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) (v2.0.5), and the filter widget you are using will only work with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (currently v2.25.0).

The original tablesorter uses `"tablesorter-headerSortUp"` which is actually the name used for a descending sort (it's backwards for some reason). Whereas the fork uses `"tablesorter-headerAsc"`, set by the [`cssAsc` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssasc). There is also a `cssDesc` (set to `"tablesorter-headerDesc"`) option.

Anyway, to get to the point...

The fork has a built-in `"tablesorter-noSort"` class (set by the [`cssNoSort` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssnosort) which is applied to the header cell.

If you included an icon in the [`headerTemplate` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headertemplate), then you can set the [`cssIconNone` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssiconnone) to target the icon.

Comment: One unrelated note: the `sortInitialOrder` is not meant to be inside the `widgetOptions`.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the comment, Definately will dig into this on Monday. I noticed it was backwards, thought I was taking crazy pills.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out a solution, albeit a workaround using HTML5 which may not be the best possible usage however,

`.tablesorter-header:not(.tablesorter-headerSortUp):not(.tablesorter-headerSortDown)`

Will apply CSS to all headers which are not sorted up or down